# Is there any way to Export an Adobe Lightroom People View?

Tags: lightroom, adobe

I'm working on a large set of photos scanned from family albums and want to share them **with the labels that I've added to identify each person that I've identified.**

I don't know how to phrase this unambiguously so I'm attaching a screenshot of what I want to export.

[image]

I want to post such photos to a website where my family could help identify people whom I don't know, correct my mistakes, add stories, etc.

By the way, I think that Adobe would increase loyalty to LightRoom if they made this function available <sub>(or revealed how to do it)</sub>.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I don't have a lightroom CC subscription, but is it possible to collaborate on [Lightroom Web](https://lightroom.adobe.com/) with your family? [This old post](https://feedback.photoshop.com/conversations/lightroom-desktop-cloudbased/lightroom-web-new-people-function-not-available-at-lightroomadobecom/5f5f45f74b561a3d426b8568) indicates the people view is not available, but perhaps that has changed?

Comment: Lightroom Web seems to be just for editing photos online.  Adobe has other sites, most of which seem to be confusing.  Thank you for the suggestion.  I'll look at other Adobe sites.

Comment: One could argue that editing metadata (ie the names of people in a photo) is also editing. Perhaps that function is hidden in LR Web somewhere?

Comment: Does LR Web require that all of her family members would also need subscriptions to participate? I doubt that family members not into photography are going to be willing to pay a monthly subscription fee to do that.

Comment: I briefly checked LR web. It does not require a subscription, but it also does not allow you to edit People information. It does allow you to edit title, description, starts, pick/reject flags and keywords, but once you share the image with others, they cannot edit that information.